# How to verify a checksum using one command line?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, checksum

Suppose I type and run the following command:

```
sha256sum ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

After a delay, this outputs the following:

```
5748706937539418ee5707bd538c4f5eabae485d17aa49fb13ce2c9b70532433  ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Then, I realize that I should have typed the following command to more rapidly assess whether the SHA‐256 hash matches:

```
sha256sum ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso | grep 5748706937539418ee5707bd538c4f5eabae485d17aa49fb13ce2c9b70532433
```

Is there a way to act on the first output without using the `sha256sum` command to verify the checksum a second time (i.e., to avoid the delay that would be caused by doing so)? Specifically:

1. I'd like to know how to do this using a command that **does not** require copy and pasting of the first output's checksum (if it's possible).
2. I'd like to know the simplest way to do this using a command that **does** require copy and pasting of the first output's checksum. (Simply attempting to use `grep` on a double‐quoted pasted checksum (i.e., as a string) doesn't work.)

Comment: Duplicate; https://superuser.com/questions/296882/linux-bash-shell-copy-previous-lines-not-history-with-keyboard

Comment: Is the only reason you don't want to use copy-paste is that you believe it doesn't work? Either `echo 'pasted string' | grep pattern` or, in shells that provide here-strings, `grep pattern <<< 'pasted string'` should work.

Comment: Related: [Super User: How to take sha256sum of file and compare to check in one line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1312740/how-to-take-sha256sum-of-file-and-compare-to-check-in-one-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1: I'd like to know how to do this using a command that does not require copy and pasting of the first output's checksum (if it's possible).

`Bash` provides no mechanism to recall any output from the previously run command. You have to capture it explicitly if you intend to act on it in any subsequent commands.

> Q2: I'd like to know the simplest way to do this using a command that does require copy and pasting of the first output's checksum. (Simply attempting to use grep on a double‐quoted pasted checksum (i.e., as a string) doesn't work.)

So your only option here is to copy/paste the output from the previous command. With respect to why this wasn't working for you when you attempted it. This likely failed because when you use `echo <sha1sum>` you introduced an additional character, a newline (`\n`) which altered the checksum string.

When echoing strings to any of the hash functions like `md5` or `sha256sum` it's generally best to do an `echo -n <..>` which tells `echo` to omit appending a newline at the end of the string.

You can see how this can influence any calls to a hash function like so:

```
$ echo "blah" | sha256sum
41af286dc0b172ed2f1ca934fd2278de4a1192302ffa07087cea2682e7d372e3  -

$ echo -n "blah" | sha256sum
8b7df143d91c716ecfa5fc1730022f6b421b05cedee8fd52b1fc65a96030ad52  -
```

The true hash of the string 'blah' is the 2nd call.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: by "attempting to use grep on a double‐quoted pasted checksum (i.e., as a string)", I meant that I attempted to use `"5748706937539418ee5707bd538c4f5eabae485d17aa49fb13ce2c9b70532433" | grep "5748706937539418ee5707bd538c4f5eabae485d17aa49fb13ce2c9b70532433"` which results in the output `5748706937539418ee5707bd538c4f5eabae485d17aa49fb13ce2c9b70532433: command not found`. Adding `echo` as described in your answer results in the desired behavior.

Answer (score 17):

You can create a simple function in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` configurations and run it in the following way:

```
sha256 <expected-sha-256-sum> <name-of-the-file>
```

It will compare the expected sha256 sum with the actual one in a single command.

The function is:

```
sha256() {
    printf '%s %s\n' "$1" "$2" | sha256sum --check
}
```

Please [find more details here](https://github.com/Shpota/sha256check).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're checking matches. Did you consider using the `-c` (`--check`) option to `sha256sum`?

Comment: Using your answer, the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM#Check_the_iso_file, and the files at http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/, I was able to figure how to perform an automated check using the command `sha256sum --check --ignore-missing SHA256SUMS`.

Comment: I chose to mark slm's post as the accepted answer because they made a direct attempt to answer the questions posed. I upvoted this answer since it's quite useful, however.

Answer (score 3):

Good idea @Sasha. Folks, pay attention that you need to put two spaces between $1 and $2.

```
sha256() { echo "$1  $2"|sha256sum -c; }
```

For an one shot solution, you could use:

```
echo "<expected-sha-256-sum>  <name-of-the-file>" | sha256sum -c
```

Again, it's important having two spaces between "expected-sha-256-sum" and "name-of-the-file".

Comment: it makes no sense to me you are insisting you need two spaces to work, why?

Comment: Actually on the Mac the 2 spaces are indeed necessary when using shasum. This cost me a lot of time until Euler's comment led me to try with 2 spaces and that worked.

Comment: It's understandable that a Mac solution is under-appreciated on this question, since it's tagged Ubuntu. I don't know off-hand if we have a Mac-specific sha256sum question, but I think it'd be valuable here to edit the answer to specify that the "two space" advice applies to a Mac environment.

Answer (score 1):

@Sasha has the right way. If you received a `SHA256SUM` file with the hash on the left and file path on the right, you can use this method:

```bash
sha256sum --check SHA256SUM 2>/dev/null | grep 'OK'
```

If not, you can create/append to a file of checksums for record-keeping and then compute the hash to compare against it:

```bash
function checksums {
    echo "$3 $2" | tee -a SHA256SUMS
    "$1" --check SHA256SUMS 2>/dev/null | grep 'OK'
}

checksums sha256sum 'ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' '5748706937539418ee5707bd538c4f5eabae485d17aa49fb13ce2c9b70532433'
```

That way, you have a record of all of the files and hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line like this:

On Linux:

```
check=$(sha256sum -b linuxmint-20.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso); check_escaped_space=$(echo $check | sed 's/ / \\/'); grep $check_escaped_space mint_sha256sum.txt -n
```

On Mac:

```
check=$(shasum -a 256 -b linuxmint-20.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso); check_escaped_space=$(echo $check | sed 's/ / \\/'); grep $check_escaped_space mint_sha256sum.txt -n
```

I used mint_sha256sum.txt as a file of correct hashes to check from like they give for https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=288 here https://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/linuxmint.com/stable/20.2/sha256sum.txt, it should give output

> 2:50b833f1f093c029bfb7ba6148c9ce96619c01a83e92f35287983fbd62f26b01
> *linuxmint-20.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso

which indicates that it matched line 2 in the .txt file.

If you don't have the hash value file and just have the expected hash then you can just put the hash in a file with a space then star and the name of the file you're checking, or so it's like the expected output of the sha256sum command.

On the [website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.3&architecture=amd64) you were downloading from it says to check it like this:

Linux:

```
echo "50b833f1f093c029bfb7ba6148c9ce96619c01a83e92f35287983fbd62f26b01 *linuxmint-20.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso" | sha256sum --check
```

Mac:

```
echo "50b833f1f093c029bfb7ba6148c9ce96619c01a83e92f35287983fbd62f26b01 *linuxmint-20.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check
```

Answer (score 0):

Many software projects provide a checksum file `some-release.zip.sha256` in addition to the downloadable file `some-release.zip`.

On one hand, the filename-checksum entries in `.sha256` files use relative paths. On the other hand, the `sha256sum` command takes the current working directory from which it is called into account.

Assuming `some-release.zip.sha256` is located within directory `/tmp/`, the following example invocation will work regardless of the current working directory, and will keep the current working directory after execution as it was before execution:

```
(cd /tmp/ && sha256sum --check some-release.zip.sha256)
```

On successful checksum verification, it will print

```
some-release.zip: OK
```

to *stdout* and exit with exit status `0`.

Answer (score -1):

One Liner:

```
echo `cat <sha256_file_name>` | sha256sum -c
```

don't forget the quotes around cat statement

Comment: What does that `echo` do?

Answer (score -1):

```
grep `sha256 file` checksum.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).